# Is it possible to use MessagingCenter or Intents with Xamarin.UI tests?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest, messagingcenter

I am writing Xamarin.UI tests for my Xamarin.Forms application. I am wondering if it is possible to simulate messages from MessagingCenter with tests? Or maybe send an Intent that will be captured by the Android application?

I would like to simulate the inputs/outputs from some hardware, which is communicating it's status with MessagingCenter inside my application.

If anyone has encountered a similar situation or has determined that it is impossible to do this, I would be glad if they share their experience.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I am curious, why do you want to use MessagingCenter in Xamarin.UI tests?

Comment: Hey, as I mentioned in the question, I would like to simulate some outputs from specific hardware, and see how the UI responds. The hardware is communicationg with Xamarin.Android application via intents, and then I use MessagingCenter to send those events to the Xamarin.Forms application.

Comment: So for example I would like to see, if a popup will appear if hardware will report status X, or if some label will change color if hardware will report status Y :)

Comment: Okey, thanks for explaining. If in Xamarin.Android application, this should be possible. You can show some code in question.

Comment: Hey, I have managed to solve this. You can check my answer. I had no knowledge about this backdoor methods before, but they are indeed a neat thing to help with UI testing :)

Comment: Great ,thanks for replying and glad you find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have managed to achieve was I was looking for with a neat thing that I didn't know of until now -> [Backdoor methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors)

I have added a backdoor method to my MainActivity.cs, which receives the hardware status from the UITests, and then sends it to my Forms application via MessagingCenter.

Backdoor method in MainActivity.cs:

```
[Export("BackdoorSendStatus")]
public void BackdoorSendStatus(string status)
{
    // In through the backdoor - do some work.
    MessagingCenter.Send(App.Instance, "StatusTopic", status);
}
```

Test case that uses this metod:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Backdoor()
{
    App.Invoke("BackdoorSendStatus", "OFFLINE");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    App.Invoke("BackdoorSendStatus", "ONLINE");
}
```